# ggpubr scatterplot median of all values on x axis

Tags: scatter-plot, median, ggpubr

Hi All I have a scatterplot and simply need to add a label to show the median of all values on the x axis. Everything I have tried gives me the value for each point on the x axis.

```
ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
add = "reg.line",                                 
conf.int = TRUE,                                  
add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"))+
stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 3, label.y = 30)+
stat_summary(fun.data = function(x) data.frame(y=30, label = 
paste("Median=",median(x))), geom="text")
```

How do I get the stat_summary function to calculate all values on the x axis?

(note this must be simple; sorry I just cant figure it out!).

Result is a single label for the median of each axis